# Problem with Constraints on Scipy Minimize function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, finance, portfolio

My goal is to optimize the weight in a portfolio of 40 stocks,  returns and risks are in a df dataframe with 40 rows and 2 columns.

For this optimization, i use the minimize function by scipy.

An asset cannot have a weight greater than 0.1 (10%) (bounds).
There are also two constraints (cons):

- 1st constraint : the sum of weights is equal to 1
- 2nd constraint:  the sum of weights of assets with a weight greater than 0.05 must not exceed 0.4 (i.e. 40% of the total weight of the portfolio)

My problem is on the 2nd constraint, i try to find a way to represent this as an inequality but without success :

`{"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: -np.sum(x[x>=0.05]) + 0.4}`

This inequality look good to me but it doesn't work when i optimize.
The sum of weights greater or equal to 0.05 (5%) is always greater than 0.4 (40%)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint

# Set the number of rows in the DataFrame (here we put 40)
n = 40

# Generate 40 random codes as a list
codes = [''.join(np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 2)) + str(np.random.randint(10, 100)) for _ in range(n)]

# Generate 40 random returns between 0.05 and 0.2
returns = np.random.uniform(0.05, 0.2, n)

# Generate 40 random risks between 0.15 and 0.39
risks = np.random.uniform(0.15, 0.39, n)

# Create the DataFrame using a dictionary
data = {"Code_title": codes, "Return": returns, "Risk": risks}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set parameters
guess = np.full((df.shape[0],1), 1.0/df.shape[0]) # initial weights for iterations
bounds = tuple((0,0.1) for x in range(df.shape[0]))  # set assets weight between 0 and 0.1 
cons = (# sum of weights = 1 
    {"type":"eq", "fun": lambda x: np.sum(x)-1},
    **#5 10 constraints
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: -np.sum(x[x>=0.05]) + 0.4})**

def function_obj(W) :

        #objective function extended maximum sharpe ration model
        W = np.array(W)
        fund_return = np.array(df['Return']) @ W # portfolio return
        fund_risk = np.array(df['Risk']) @ W # portfolio risk 

        return fund_return/fund_risk # objective function

result = minimize(function_obj, guess,  method = "SLSQP", bounds=bounds, constraints=cons)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
result['x']

np.sum(result['x'][result['x']>=0.05]) # calculate the sum of weights greater than 0.05
```

Comment: The second constraint is discontinuous. Either you can add binary variables, constraints to those and use a MINLP-supporting method like `differential_evolution`, or do something else exotic like an exhaustive outer loop that attempts all combinations of "high weight" constraints.

Comment: You can also try making 0.05 a "soft constraint" through a nonlinear cost term, and iteratively strengthen this term.

Comment: Can you represent the objective not as `fund_return/fund_risk` but as `fund_return-fund_risk`? If so this will become way easier

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the first approach is to replace your objective with a linear one. There are several possible forms, each looking like a dot product of some constant vector with your decision weights. This constant vector could be an element-wise (not sum-wise) ratio of risk to return, or it could be a (potentially weighted) difference of risk and return.

Construct a mixed-integer linear program:

```py
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, LinearConstraint, milp

n = 40
rand = default_rng(seed=0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code_title': [  # FM85, etc.
        ''.join((*rand.choice(tuple(string.ascii_uppercase), 2), str(x)))
        for x in rand.integers(10, 100, size=n)
    ],
    'Return': rand.uniform(0.05, 0.2, n),
    'Risk': rand.uniform(0.15, 0.39, n),
})

# or df.Risk / df.Return (though this is element-wise and not a sum)
# or df.Risk * risk_coefficient + df.Return * return_coefficient
risk_return = df.Risk - df.Return

# Decision variables: n low-weights, n high-weights, n high-weight assignments
c = np.hstack((
    # Minimize risk, maximize return
    risk_return, risk_return,
    # High-weight assignments are not optimized
    np.zeros(n),
))

# Low-weights are continuous, high-weights are semicontinuous, assignments are integral
integrality = np.hstack((
    np.zeros(n), np.full(n, 2), np.ones(n),
))

bounds = Bounds(
    lb=np.hstack((
        np.zeros(n),
        np.full(n, 0.05 + 1e-6),
        np.zeros(n),
    )),
    ub=np.hstack((
        np.full(n, 0.05),
        np.full(n, 0.10),
        np.ones(n),
    )),
)

# sum of weights is equal to 1
weight_sum = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.hstack((np.ones(2*n), np.zeros(n))), lb=1, ub=1,
)
# if a weight is low and nonzero, it cannot be assigned high
low_asn = LinearConstraint(  # loweight + highasn <= 1
    A=np.hstack((np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n)), np.eye(n))), lb=0, ub=1,
)
# if a weight is high, it must be assigned high
high_asn_on = LinearConstraint(  # highweight - highasn * 0.05 >= 0
    A=np.hstack((np.zeros((n, n)), np.eye(n), -0.05*np.eye(n))), lb=0, ub=np.inf,
)
high_asn_off = LinearConstraint(  # -highweight + highasn >= 0
    A=np.hstack((np.zeros((n, n)), -np.eye(n), np.eye(n))), lb=0, ub=np.inf,
)
# sum of weights of assets with a weight greater than 0.05 must not exceed 0.4
high_sum = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.hstack((np.zeros(n), np.ones(n), np.zeros(n))), lb=0, ub=0.4,
)

result = milp(
    c=c, integrality=integrality, bounds=bounds,
    constraints=(weight_sum, low_asn, high_asn_on, high_asn_off, high_sum),
)
assert result.success, result.message

df['low_weight'], df['high_weight'], df['high_assigned'] = np.split(result.x, (n, 2*n))
nonzero_weights = df[df.iloc[:, -3:].any(axis=1)]
print(nonzero_weights)
```

```
   Code_title    Return      Risk  low_weight  high_weight  high_assigned
8        JR25  0.104767  0.159723        0.05          0.0            0.0
11       SK92  0.189073  0.156808        0.00          0.1            1.0
13       PS64  0.193189  0.153838        0.00          0.1            1.0
17       SX58  0.199264  0.165860        0.00          0.1            1.0
19       NJ94  0.119007  0.166006        0.05          0.0            0.0
20       RO34  0.163659  0.232634        0.05          0.0            0.0
24       TK45  0.112198  0.212128        0.05          0.0            0.0
25       IX87  0.160173  0.208002        0.05          0.0            0.0
27       SQ13  0.189809  0.204209       -0.00          0.1            1.0
29       JV75  0.159352  0.219199        0.05          0.0            0.0
30       KU86  0.189114  0.290670        0.05          0.0            0.0
31       IG25  0.195189  0.282982        0.05          0.0            0.0
34       RI11  0.197179  0.219221        0.05          0.0            0.0
35       OD58  0.193582  0.249095        0.05         -0.0           -0.0
37       XU36  0.195894  0.300362        0.05          0.0            0.0
39       TB48  0.173356  0.238657        0.05          0.0            0.0
```

This will *not* be equivalent to the objective that you originally wrote, but if you don't have some strict theoretical need for it then maybe that's OK.

The other options addressing the original nonlinear objective (soft sigmoid constraints, differential evolution MINLP) will be more computationally complex.